# Bar plot in r with categorical variable

Tags: r

Its pretty straight forward but I am unable to do it in r

I want to plot the below information in bar plot with state in x axis.

```
state Avg_Earning
 A         200
 B         350
 C         280
 D         520
```

Comment: ``barplot(dat$Avg_Earning, names=dat$state)``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barplot will solve the problem.

```
Data <- data.frame(state = LETTERS[1:4], Avg_Earning = c(200, 350, 280, 520))

barplot(Data$Avg_Earning, names.arg = Data$state)
```

Comment: Can we put values on top of each bar?

Comment: got it...text(x = xx, y = data$Avg_Earning, label = data$Avg_Earning, pos = 1, cex = 0.8, col = "black")